# How to represent media as individual entities?

Tags: 8, entities, media

I need some architectural advice please.

I'm building a Drupal 8 site for the first time and I need to represent audio and video media on the site.

There are probably fields I can use but I'm looking for a solution which will allow each video or audio to be represented as individual entities on the site so I can list one audio/video entity in multiple locations on the site.

Can anyone advice on how best I should implement my media requirements?

Comment: Use the media_entity set of modules, and be aware of the coming changes in 8.4.x+ that incorporates media to core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a module called [Media entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity). Some more details about it, from its project page:

> Media entity provides a 'base' entity for media. This is a very basic entity which can reference to all kinds of media-objects (local files, YouTube videos, Tweets, Instagram photos, ...). Media entity provides a relation between Drupal and the media resource. You can reference to/use this entity within any other Drupal entity.
>
> This module attempts to provide the base storage component for the Drupal 8 media ecosystem.

I think that it will do what you want.